# Rewriting a piecewise function to Heaviside function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do i turn this piecewise function to a Heaviside function?
$$
x(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
t^{3}, & |t|<2 \\
0, & |t|>2
\end{array}\right.
$$

The solution is: $$
x(t)=t^{3}(H(t+2)-H(t-2))
$$
but I dont know how to get this

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what $H(t), H(t+2)$ and $H(t-2)$ mean? Do you know what $|t|<2$ means?

Comment: what I got was $$
t^{3}-t^{3} H(t-2)+0 \cdot H(t-2)
$$

Comment: $H(t-2)$ is 1 when $t \ge 2$ so $t^3H(t-2)$ is $t^3$ when $t \ge 2$ and 0 otherwise. Then $t^3-t^3H(t-2)$ is $t^3$ when $t<2$ and 0 otherwise. The problem is maybe that you don't get the meaning of $|t|<2$, which is that $t$ is between -2 nd 2.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, the function t^3 is switched of from -infinity to t = -2 then its switched on by the Heaviside function and then gets switched off again after t = 2?

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the definition of $H$, and combining the right parts of piecewise functions together:

$$H(t+2) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } t < -2 \\ 1 & \text{if } t\ge-2 \end{cases} \\
H(t-2) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } t < 2 \\ 1 & \text{if } t\ge2\end{cases} \\ 
\implies \color{red}{H(t+2)}-\color{blue}{H(t-2)} = \begin{cases} \color{red}0-\color{blue}0 = 0 & \text{if } t < -2 \\
\color{red}1-\color{blue}0 = 1 & \text{if } -2 \le t < 2 \\
\color{red}1-\color{blue}1 = 0 & \text{if } t \ge 2 \end{cases}$$